# Pulseaudio playing surround through headset

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am using XUbuntu 10.04, and I am having issues with the sound. First things just sounded strange, then I figured out that I am actually getting the surround left and surround right sound in my headset. If I change the balance in aumix to either far left or far right, things sound better. I still get sound in both headphones, but only the left or right channel.

If I do [`speaker-test -c6`](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/audio/alsa-utils/docs/reference/available-utilities) (man page), it becomes clear that I am missing the center channel.

In `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` I have set default-sample-channels = 2

Is there a way for pulseaudio to downmix from surround to stereo for the ouptut?

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111428/209677) Unix SE answer might be useful

Answer (score 1):

In System -> Preferences -> Sound

- Select Hardware
- Select your device
- Choose the profile you want (like Analog stereo output)
- Select output
- Check your device

Comment: It's already on analog stereo output. I have no surround options in sound preferences.